# sending image as a parameter in xmlhttprequest Post method failed

Tags: javascript, forms, xmlhttprequest

I am new to JavaScript. In this first i sent successfully some data as a parameters in xmlhttprequest post method. But after that i am trying to send Image as a parameter but this time the post method fails.Here i am using content-type as a `multipart/form-data`

I am successfully sent image as a parameter in post method.But this time i used `<form>` tag.

Please any one tell me about this? why my first procedure fails?

```
function store(){
var pname=document.getElementById("pname").value;
var price=document.getElementById("price").value;
var discount=document.getElementById("discount").value;
var desc=document.getElementById("desc").value;
var heading=document.getElementById("heading").value;
var image=document.getElementById("image").value;

 var params="pname="+pname+"&price="+price+"&discount="+discount+"&desc="+desc+"&heading="+heading+"&image="+image;

var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{// code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {             
           var txt=xmlhttp.responseText;
           var obj = eval ("(" + txt + ")");
           if(obj.success)
           {
           userlogin(obj.username,obj.password);
            }
           else
           document.location.href="Userregistration.jsp";
           //document.getElementById("countryname").innerHTML=obj.CurrencyById[0].country;
           alert("Registered");
     }
 }
 xmlhttp.open("POST","Newproduct",true);
 xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "multipart/form-data");
xmlhttp.send(params);

}
```

Comment: I do only see one procedure, not the second. Could you please post it?

Comment: What is `params`? The rest of the code is irrelevant.

Comment: Hi Bergi, i added extra content in my code please check it.